# Recover from possibly corrupt Core Data database

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS app which stores it's data in a Core Data database. The basic structure has Libraries and Items, with a many-to-many relationship between them represented by LibraryItemMapping. The mapping item contains an index, so that items can be sorted differently in different containers. This works fine most of the time, but on my own device which I use for dev/test, I am running into situations where the Core Data objects are returning nil for one side or the other of those relationships. If I enumerate those objects at launch (via code in AppDelegate), the nils disappear and I'm able to retrieve objects on either side of the relationship, but when looking for the same relationships just a few seconds later they begin to return nil. This, for example, always runs OK and never errors out or finds any nils:

```
public func runConsistencyCheck() {
    do {
        let mappings = try dataContext.fetch(NSFetchRequest<LibraryItemMapping>(entityName: "LibraryItemMapping"))
        for map in mappings {
            if (map.item==nil || map.library==nil) {
                print("Found corrupt mapping record. Deleting.")
                dataContext.delete(map)
            }
        }
        saveContext()
    } catch {
        print("An error occurred during consistency checking: \(error)")
    }
}
```

But this regularly finds nil for `obj.item` and/or crashes on my device:

```
func getMapping(forItem item: Item) -> LibraryItemMapping? {
    if (libraryData?.itemMappings != nil) {
        for obj in libraryData!.itemMappings as! Set<LibraryItemMapping> {
            if (obj.item != nil && obj.item! == item) { return obj }
            else {
                print("Found Core Data mapping with null item data.")
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Attempting to create or modify and then save any other records results in multiple iterations of this error:

```
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"item is a required value.\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=item, NSLocalizedDescription=item is a required value., NSValidationErrorObject=<LibraryItemMapping: 0x174098060> (entity: LibraryItemMapping; id: 0xd0000000001c0000 <x-coredata://ED9F1AE5-A7D0-46FD-AC94-941E9EFEF341/LibraryItemMapping/p7> ; data: {\n    index = 4;\n    item = nil;\n    library = \"0xd000000000140004 <x-coredata://ED9F1AE5-A7D0-46FD-AC94-941E9EFEF341/LibraryData/p5>\";\n})}"
```

This only happens on the one device that I am aware of, so I'm tempted to put it down to a database corrupted by a bad debug session at some point, but at the very least I'd like to be able to clean up after it gracefully. If this were SQL, I would just run a consistency check and something like `delete from LibraryItemMapping where item is null or library is null` and move on, but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent with Core Data. How can I troubleshoot this further, and how can I gracefully recover from a seemingly corrupt database?

Answer (score 2):

After pulling the sqlite files from the device and digging through the raw data, this actually turned out to be a data model bug. During app startup it goes through a "prune old records" step, and inconsistent delete rules on the relationships for the linking table allowed it to leave records in an inconsistent state. After correcting the delete rules to use `Cascade` or `Nullify` as appropriate, everything is working again.

Comment: Ran into something like this today. We'd added a parent/child relationship where the parent did not have `Cascade` specified, and the child had a required relationship to its parent. When the parent was deleted, the delete failed, and any subsequent operations on the managed object context failed. What made it difficult to debug was that we didn't detect the error until we went to save data unrelated to the deleted parent.